# Copiando de um arquivo para uma matriz

Tags: c

Boa noite,estou com um problema, estou querendo copiar uma informação de um arquivo para uma matriz que aloco dinamicamente, o arquivo texto contem isso:

```
....*
*....
.....
.*...
.....
```

(5 linhas e 5 colunas que irão para a matriz que aloquei usando realloc pois não sei o numero de linhas e de colunas que as informações de dentro do arquivo possuem).

Eu preciso copiar isso para uma matriz, mas lembrando que não sei o tamanho do arquivo então tenho que usar feof.
Estou com um problema de segmentação e não sei aonde, e estou com duvidas se a passagem do ponteiro de arquivo e o processo dentro da função "leitura" esta sendo feito de uma forma correta.Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** leitura(char* nome)//Declaracao de funcao que aloca a matriz
{
    FILE* ponteiro;
    int i = 0,j = 1, k ,l;
    char** campo = NULL;
    char carac;

    ponteiro = fopen("nome", "w");

    while(!feof(ponteiro))
    {
        i++;
        campo = (char**) realloc(campo, i * sizeof(char*));     

        while(fscanf(ponteiro, "%c", &carac) != '\n')
        {
            campo[j - 1] = (char*) realloc(campo[j - 1], j * sizeof(char));
            campo[i - 1][j - 1] = carac;
            j++;    
        }
    }

    for(k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        for(l = 0; l < j; l++)
        {
            printf("%c", campo[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(ponteiro);

    return campo; //Retorno da matriz alocada dinamicamente
}

int main (void)
{
    int tamanho = 0, linha = 0, coluna = 0;
    char* nome = NULL;
    char** retornoCampo = NULL;
    size_t tam = 0;
    int i, j;

    int opcao = 0;

    scanf("%d", &opcao);


    switch(opcao) //Opcoes a serem escolhidas
    {
        case 1: //Leitura
            getline(&nome, &tam, stdin); //Funcao para adquirir o nome do arquivo
            nome[strlen(nome) - 1] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", nome);
            retornoCampo = leitura(nome);

            break;
        case 2: //Inicializacao do tabuleiro
            break;
        case 3: //Acao do usuario
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debugger a la carte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ponteiro = fopen("nome", "w");` <== isto vai abrir o ficheiro para escrita (**w**rite) e esvaziá-lo. Deves fazer `ponteiro = fopen("nome", "r");`
2. O uso `while(!feof(ponteiro))` é incorrecto. A função `feof()` indica se o último acesso ao *stream* deu erro; não indica se o próximo acesso vai falhar porque não há mais dados disponiveis (não existe nenhuma função em C que faça isto!). O que deves fazer é (tentar) ler dados normalmente e, caso haja erro, acabar o ciclo. Se quiseres podes verificar se o erro se deveu a falta de dados ou a outro motivo qualquer (quebra de rede, bad sector no disco, ...).
3. Em C, fazer o *cast* ao resultado do `malloc()` é redundante e pode esconder um erro que o compilador acharia se não estivesse lá esse *cast*. Sugiro que deixes de fazer a conversão explícita aos valores devolvidos por `malloc()` (ou `calloc()`) e `realloc()`.
4. `while(fscanf(ponteiro, "%c", &carac) != '\n')` Este while entra em ciclo infinito. O resultado do teu `fscanf()` só pode ser um de três valores, nomeadamente `1`, `0`, ou `EOF`. Como `'\n'` é diferente de qualquer destes valores o ciclo nunca termina. O valor devolvido pelo `fscanf()` será `EOF` se houve erro de leitura (fim de dados no ficheiro, quebra de rede, bad sector, ...); será `1` se o `fscanf()` conseguiu atribuir um valor à variável `carac` e será `0` se não conseguiu atribuir valor.

E para já fico-me por aqui.

Edit: o teu ciclo pode, provavelmente, ser assim

```
    while (fscanf(ponteiro, "%c", &carac) == 1) {
        if (carac == '\n') break;
        // ...
    }
```